# Definite integrals involving Bessel functions

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am looking for a closed-form expression for the following integral:
$$
 I_1 = \int_{0}^{\infty} J_{2m} \left(  a x\right) x \dfrac{ e^{-j \sqrt{k^2-x^2} b}}{ \sqrt{k^2-x^2}}    \textrm{d} x 
$$
where $J_{2m}(\cdot)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind and order $2m$, with $m$ integer. A series representation would also be useful.

Other integrals for which I am looking for a closed-form expression are
$$
I_2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} { x^{1/2} e^{-a x }  J_{2n-1/2}( b x )  J_0 \left( c x \right)     \textrm{d} x }
$$
and
$$
I_3 = \int_{0}^{\infty} { x^{1/2} e^{-a x }  J_{2n-1/2}( b x )  J_1 \left( c x \right)     \textrm{d} x }
$$
where $n$ is an integer.